# Can Racket get free disk space statistics without executing and parsing the output of external executables?

Tags: racket

I'm looking for a way to use native Racket methods of getting some statistics about the host machine the application is running on like free disk space, memory use and processor use. So far I haven't found a library that reports this information within Racket; is there an idiomatic method to get this information or is the only way to find external executables and parse the results on each platform the application runs on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confident that you're not going to find this functionality in a library that's bundled with Racket. On the other hand, I see no reason why this couldn't be implemented as a Racket library that does not use an external executable. I'm not saying that it is, only that it almost certainly *can* be implemented as a library. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sounds like the ability to get free disk space (and some of these other stats) isn't part of Racket's current functionality, so if that's an accurate translation, I suppose it does...

Comment: I think I would broadly agree with you, but being a persnickety and defensive person I would say that these features *are* technically "part of the current functionality": you can just make the appropriate operating-system specific calls to obtain this information, whatever those calls are. I personally have NO IDEA what those calls might be, which is why my answer, while accurate, is pretty unhelpful.